# How to do this kind of tables in R

Tags: r, crosstable

I need to do a table, like the one below, in R, it has continuous variables in the rows that needs to be separated into two categories (in the image is men and women) and calculate the mean and sd (that has to be between brackets) for each of the two groups.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtJdB.png)

I hope I explained myself all right, really hope you could help me because I can't find anywhere how to do it.

Thanks so much

I have tried crosstables and summarize functions but it does not seem to work.

Comment: https://finalfit.org/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable

Comment: If you want code as an answer, we need to see some of your actual data (no image, only code using `dput()` if needed).